# Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/JspFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootJpa1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootJpa1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.secure</groupId>
            <artifactId>SecurityDemo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Seeing this error !

Comment: Use spring-boot 3.x

Comment: With spring boot 2.x,  `servlet` package is `javax` not `jakarta`

Answer (score 2):

*Java EE* became *Jakarta EE* when Oracle Corp donated the technologies to the Eclipse Foundation.

During this transition, the package naming of the various APIs changed from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`.

- Spring Boot 2 supports the old naming: `javax.*`
- Spring Boot 3 supports the new naming: `jakarta.*`

I would recommend going with Spring Boot 3 and [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/). Be sure to study the release notes as many changes happened in this major new version.

If you use any libraries that rely on the old naming, you’ll have to stick with Spring Boot 2 and the older Java EE APIs and naming.

---

This Jakarta transition has been covered thoroughly by the industry press. You might want to occasionally read that press to keep yourself abreast of such changes.